# I've gathered a bounty that I can't afford to pay off. What do I do?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

After an train robbery that got out severely of hand I have acquired a $700 bounty in the Heartlands region. I don't have the money to pay it off and now I am regularly pursued by bounty hunters. I've already gathered the gold bars from the treasure maps so I can't use that as an easy source of cash to pay the bounty either.

In the original Red Dead Redemption some missions provided Marston with a bounty pardon. Do these exist in Red Dead Redemption 2? If not, how else could I deal with this high of a bounty?

Comment: There's a bridge on the northern borders of lemoyne. If you have a bounty in lemoyne the big red border crosses this bridge so it's easy to identify. You can stay on the west end of that bridge. The bounty hunters always spawn in the swamps and always cross the bridge on horses. You can pluck them off easily and loot your way to paying that bounty off in no time. Sit there, kill 4 or 5 waves until all they give you is tonics, head to the fence, sell off everything, buy more bullets, go back to bridge. You'll have that bounty paid off in an hour or two. You can loot horse saddlebags too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only options for clearing a bounty are either paying it off, or surrender and go to jail. The latter is only possible when your wanted level is low, so if you've been shooting up some law enforcement you will likely be shot dead if you surrender. To clarify: there is **no** decay or decrease in bounty over time!

When you surrender, you'll have to wait out your sentence in jail. [This page](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-12-21-red-dead-redemption-2-bounty-wanted-how-to-pay-bounties-lose-wanted-level-4975) claims that you *could* be rescued by friends whilst your in jail, but I haven't seen that happen myself. Granted, I haven't spent a lot of time in jail.

To surrender (from [IGN Wiki](https://www.ign.com/wikis/red-dead-redemption-2/How_to_Clear_Your_Bounty)):

> If you bounty is low enough, you can sometimes simply surrender to the nearest lawman before things escalate by targeting them and pressing Y or Triangle to surrender, and putting away your weapons. You'll spend a few in-game days in jail, and the fine will be paid automatically.

Comment: Unfortunate. I still do not want to be pursued by bounty hunters so I think I'll just have to reload an older save state.